# I am trying to load a pdf in webview from a website link in my android application ,but getting failed in that

Tags: android, webview

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf="http://www.ashwinikidneycentre.com/asset/Kidney-Book-In`English.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: Try this link http://weimenglee.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-tip-displaying-pdf-document.html

Comment: You can go through with this link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-webview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webview loadRequest not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491062/webview-loadrequest-not-working)

Comment: That is because your url is not existing. Have you tried to open `http://www.ashwinikidneycentre.com/asset/Kidney-Book-In`English.pdf` in the browser?

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue in the line:

```
String pdf="http://www.ashwinikidneycentre.com/asset/Kidney-Book-In`English.pdf";
```

The proper url is `www.ashwinikidneycentre.com/asset/Kidney-Book-In-English.pdf`

Try:
`String pdf="www.ashwinikidneycentre.com/asset/Kidney-Book-In-English.pdf"`

Comment: I tried String pdf="www.ashwinikidneycentre.com/asset/Kidney-Book-In-English.pdf" also not working. while i am appending to  google drive it asking for login and through google doc it is showing no preview available